# Image size that fits the whole background od UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

I'd like to add a backround image to my UITableView, that fits the UI, that has also navigationcontroller and toolbar. I did not find anywhere the size of the image the fits a tableview for different screens of iPhone and iPad in that case.

Comment: Why don't you log the tableView's frame in the `viewDidAppear` method? Then you can see the size on any device. Keep in mind that things can change. What do you want to do when the user uses your app while on a phone call, for example? In this case the frame will be smaller than normal. It's also a bad idea to assume any specific size. iOS 7 could bring different sizes (possibly).

Comment: You have right, but I thought there would be some official guide about it by Apple like for a lot of things in their hig and so on.

Comment: There are too many variables for this one. Lots of devices and orientations. Whether the status bar is showing or not, whether the toolbar is showing or not. Apple can't chart every combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard height of toolbars and navigation bars in portrait mode is 44 points, the status bar is 20 points, so a table view in a navigation controller with toolbar would have 372 points left on an iPhone with a 3.5" screen (480 - 2 * 44 - 20), and 460 on a 4" screen (568 - 2 * 44 - 20). In landscape mode, the bars are just 32 points high (only on the iPhone though, on an iPad, there's no difference)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you set the background of the table view to clear color :

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```